# "DistanceCombiner" option of Dendrogram – what is it?

Tags: undocumented, cluster-analysis

[`Dendrogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dendrogram.html) has the following non-graphics options:

```
KeyComplement[{Options[Dendrogram], Options[Graphics]}]

<|DistanceFunction -> Automatic, "DistanceCombiner" -> Automatic, 
 ClusterDissimilarityFunction -> "Single", 
 "DataDissimilarityMatrix" -> Automatic|>
```

What is `"DistanceCombiner"` and what can I use it for?